# How to do base authentication to DreamFactory with jQuery and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, basic-authentication, dreamfactory

I'm trying to do a basic authentication via ajax request to DreamFactory, to get a SESSION_TOKEN (or JWT). But following code fails. The DreamFactory community forum seems to be outdated, can't post my question there. Anyone knows how to do a proper ajax call with basic authentication to DreamFactory?

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'https://<dreamfactory-server>/api/v2/user/session';
    async: true,
    type:'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa('hhmeier@blabla.com'+':'+'secret'));
    },
    success: function(response){
        console.log("hello success");
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log("hello error " + err.responseText);
    }
});
```

Executing this code shows this error message.

*{"error":{"code":400,"context":null,"message":"Login request is missing required email.","status_code":400}}*

It seems that the login needs an email address for logging. So tried it with a curl command and in the body the email and password in JSON format. This call works, it returns a SESSION_TOKEN, that works in further api calls via DreamFactory (using http only for testing, later https).

`curl -i -k -3 -X POST "http://<dreamfactory-server>/api/v2/user/session" -d '{ "email" : "hhmeier@blabla.com", "password" : "secret" }' -H "Content-Type: application/json"`

Executing curl command with basic authentication, it fails with the same error from above.

`curl -i -k -3 -X POST "http://<dreamfactory-server>/api/v2/user/session" --user hhmeier@blabla.com:secret -H "Content-Type: application/json"`

Although the DreamFactory manuals describes that Basic Authentication works, I can't make it work. Except with this curl command. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The reason the curl command fails is that you need to use HTTPS. As per the DreamFactory documentation.

```
curl https://jdoe%40dreamfactory.com:secret@foo.com/api/v2/db/_table
```

Also, in your Ajax call, you need to makes a GET call to get the endpoint.

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: url,
    async: true,
    type:'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+btoa(username+':'+password));
    },
    success: function(json){
        ...
    },
    error: function(err) {
        ...
    }
});
```

For further reference, kindly refer this article - http://wiki.dreamfactory.com/DreamFactory/Tutorials/Basic_Auth

Thanks